# How do i check for unique elements in an array and total an amount assoicated with that element

Tags: php

I'm querying a database to get this array. The output is an account number followed by the amount for that account number. As you can see there are duplicate instances of the account number. This array will always be the same, ie account number and then amount. How do I get a total of a single account number? For example the total amount for 1B2 is $10119.59.

```
Array
  (
    [0] => 1B2
    [1] => 1970.40
    [2] => 1B2
    [3] => 1493.60
    [4] => 1B2
    [5] => 1400.25
    [6] => J014 1
    [7] => 1423.20
    [8] => J014 1
    [9] => 2179.20
    [10] => J014 1
    [11] => 1432.00
    [12] => J014 1
    [13] => 711.60
    [14] => 1B2
    [15] => 298.72
    [16] => 1B2
    [17] => 1568.80
    [18] => 1B2
    [19] => 1822.62
    [20] => 1B2
    [21] => 1493.60
    [22] => J014 1
    [23] => 1400.25
    [24] => 1B2
    [25] => 711.60
    [26] => J014 1
    [27] => 1194.88
    [28] => J014 1
    [29] => 1493.60
)
```

Comment: If this is from a database, then you can probably make the database give you the total for each account.  Something like `SELECT account, SUM(total) FROM accounts GROUP BY account`.

Comment: Yes, this is from a database. But this isnt all I'm doing. I have 1000 lines of code that is getting data from the 2 databases merging and parsing information. These totals are after I do calculations like overtime and sick days and also days worked. Rate * time, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using a bunch of array functions.

```
$your_account = '1B2';
$total = array_sum(array_column(array_filter(
    array_chunk($array, 2), function($v, $k) use ($your_account) {
        return $v[0] == $your_account;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH), 1));
```

Working from inside to outside:

1. array_chunk creates a two dimensional array of account entries
2. array_filter filters the array to only entries for your account
3. array_column gets only the amount column
4. array_sum totals the
   amounts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$data = [
    0 => '1B2',
    1 => '1970.40',
    2 => '1B2',
    3 => '1493.60',
    4 => '1B2',
    5 => '1400.25',
    6 => 'J014 1',
    7 => '1423.20',
    8 => 'J014 1',
    9 => '2179.20',
    10 => 'J014 1',
    11 => '1432.00',
    12 => 'J014 1',
    13 => '711.60',
    14 => '1B2',
    15 => '298.72',
    16 => '1B2',
    17 => '1568.80',
    18 => '1B2',
    19 => '1822.62',
    20 => '1B2',
    21 => '1493.60',
    22 => 'J014 1',
    23 => '1400.25',
    24 => '1B2',
    25 => '711.60',
    26 => 'J014 1',
    27 => '1194.88',
    28 => 'J014 1',
    29 => '1493.60',
];

$temp = array();
$i = 0;
$account_key = '';

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) { //This is the account number
        $account_key = $value;
    } else {    //This is the amount
        $temp[$account_key][] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}

foreach($temp as $key => $value) { //For each account number sum the amount
    echo $key.': '.array_sum($value).'<br />';
}
```

Result:

```
1B2: 10759.59
J014 1: 9834.73
```